# How do I color a R2HTML table cell based on the value of the data in the cell?

Tags: r, r2html

I am using R2HTML to display a dataframe on an HTML page.

I want the cells of the table to be colored based on the value of the data in the cell.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do it, such as using javascript to set colors based on the value in each cell, but the easiest way might be to manually create some html in the dataframe before passing it to `HTML()`. You need to create a color ramp covering the range of your data with the color range you'd like, then assign each value in the table to one of these colors, and final paste some HTML, your color values and your data values back together before calling `HTML()` on the result.

```
data = data.frame(x=rnorm(10,10,1),y=rnorm(10,1,1))
minData<-min(data)
maxData<-max(data)
cols=colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"))(99)
dataCols = apply(data,c(1,2),FUN=function(x){paste('<p style="background-color:',cols[cut(x, breaks = seq(minData, maxData, len = 100), include.lowest = TRUE)],'">',x,'</p>',sep = "")})
HTML(dataCols)
```

Comment: Helpful answer. Sorry for the delay replying but I have been on another project for the past few days. One general point that may help others: HTML in the R2HTML package is best treated as a black box. Unless you want to hack the source code to introduce your own publish-subscribe features, or similar, decorate your table with HTML before invoking HTML, along the lines that the answer does.